# Authenticate user on twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to authenticate user on twitter to post/get tweets of user. By following this link

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/authenticate

In my file I am redirecting to this link 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=token&force_login=yes
but this return this error

"The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake"

It seems issue with token. I am using Access Token token 
https://apps.twitter.com/ from one of my app.
Is it correct or find oauth token somewhere else.
Thanks

Comment: generate a new access token from apps.twitter.com and use it in your url

Comment: generated but still same, is it confirm that access token will be use here

Comment: This may help : https://twitteroauth.com/redirect.php